# Nintendo Surgeon

Tags: riddle, word

This is part of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge (you can read more about it [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6352/fortnightly-topic-challenge-35-restricted-title-1))!

Here are the rules: You are a surgeon and you must stitch back all of the letter combinations into words in order to reveal a Nintendo game! Have fun!

> 1. Sietrt & mordia.r
> 2. Kudc tunh
> 3. prseu rimoa srob
> 4. rtas ofx
> 5. sbi'yrk eadrm ldna
> 6. mliaan rsognics
> 7. Eht gdleen fo azled the iimshn pca
> 8. sia'orw odswo
> 9. openkmo woeyll
> 10. keibeetxci
> 11. cei ermlibc
> 12. tester freight
> 13. ossi’hy lolowy roldw
> 14. uqha sf
> 15. mrdoiet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got 'em all

> 1. Sietrt & mordia.r
> Tetris & Dr. Mario
>
> 2. Kudc tunh
> Duck Hunt
>
> 3. prseu rimoa srob
> Super Mario Bros
>
> 4. rtas ofx
> Star Fox
>
> 5. sbi'yrk eadrm ldna
> Kirby's Dream Land
>
> 6. mliaan rsognics
> Animal Crossing
>
> 7. Eht gdleen fo azled the iimshn pca
> The Legend of Zelda: The Minish Cap
>
> 8. sia'orw odswo
> Wario's Woods
>
> 9. openkmo woeyll
> Pokemon Yellow
>
> 10. keibeetxci
> Excitebike
>
> 11. cei ermlibc
> Ice Ciimber
>
> 12. tester freight
> Street Fighter
>
> 13. ossi’hy lolowy roldw
> Yoshi's Woolly World
>
> 14. uqha sf
> Shaq Fu
>
> 15. mrdoiet
> Metroid

Comment: Good job and quick too!! :)